# ruby force integer division on real numbers

Tags: ruby, math

How in ruby can you force integer division of real numbers?

```
# integer division with integers - no problem
>> [ 7/2 , 7%2 ]
=> [3, 1]

# integer division with floats - '%' gives the remainder just fine...
# ...but for the quotient it used real division
>> [ 7.0/2 , 7.0%2 ]
=> [3.5, 1.0]

# This is what happens with non integer-y floats
>> [ 7.1/2 , 7.1%2 ]
=> [3.55, 1.0999999999999996]
```

I want `[ 3.0, 1.1 ]`. Suppose this cannot be done in vanilla ruby and need to use a gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
require 'bigdecimal'
d = BigDecimal.new(7.1, 2)
 => #<BigDecimal:7fc2b199ab30,'0.71E1',18(27)>
d.divmod(2).map(&:to_f)
 => [3.0, 1.1]
```

Comment: When accuracy is important, you should probably avoid floats altogether.

Comment: I put that last map just to display values, otherwise they would have been `BigDecimal` objects

Answer (score 6):

[`Numeric#divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) comes to the rescue:

```
7.1.divmod 2
#⇒ [
#  [0] 3,
#  [1] 1.0999999999999996
# ]
```

Or, for the quotient part only (credits to @Stefan):

```
7.1.div 2
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: Or `7.1.div(2)` for just the quotient part.